how to create same host gitlab in same cluster
I am planning to set up another GitLab instance with the same hostname within the same Kubernetes cluster. There is already a GitLab instance with Helm version 5.10.5 that has been set up, and now I am trying to deploy another GitLab instance with Helm version 7.11.7 in a different namespace within the same cluster. However, I encountered the following error:
Created a new Ingress called "gitlab01-kas" in gitlab01 2024-08-15T02:20:01.022661126Z
Thu, Aug 15 2024 11:20:02 amError: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: host "gitlab-dev.sdpf4hc-ntt.com" and path "/" is already defined in ingress gitlab/gitlab-webservice-default
I really need to set up another GitLab instance with the same hostname, but changing the path is also difficult. As a solution, I have tried the following steps, but the error persists:

Scoped the namespace using ingress-nginx to narrow it down.
Filtered with namespaceSelector using field.cattle.io/projectId=p-XXXX.

I believe the issue is related to limiting the namespace scope so that it doesn't watch other namespaces. Below is the values.yaml file I used for ingress-nginx:
> nginx-ingress:   controller:
>     addHeaders:
>       Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
>     admissionWebhooks:
>       enabled: false
>     config:
>       annotation-value-word-blocklist: >-
>         load_module,lua_package,_by_lua,location,root,proxy_pass,serviceaccount,{,},',"
>       hsts: 'true'
>       hsts-include-subdomains: 'false'
>       hsts-max-age: '63072000'
>       server-name-hash-bucket-size: '256'
>       server-tokens: 'false'
>       ssl-ciphers: >-
>         ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4
>       ssl-protocols: TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2
>       upstream-keepalive-connections: 100
>       upstream-keepalive-requests: 1000
>       upstream-keepalive-time: 30s
>       upstream-keepalive-timeout: 5
>       use-http2: 'true'
>     ingressClassByName: true
>     ingressClassResource:
>       name: '{{ include "ingress.class.name" $ | quote }}'
>       default: false
>       enabled: true
>     metrics:
>       enabled: true
>       service:
>         annotations:
>           gitlab.com/prometheus_port: '10254'
>           gitlab.com/prometheus_scrape: 'true'
>           prometheus.io/port: '10254'
>           prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
>     minAvailable: 1
>     publishService:
>       enabled: true
>     replicaCount: 2
>     resources:
>       requests:
>         cpu: 100m
>         memory: 100Mi
>     scope:
>       enabled: true
>       namespace: gitlab01
>       namespaceSelector: field.cattle.io/projectId= p-XXXX
>     service:
>       externalTrafficPolicy: Local
>       annotations:
>         service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path:
> /XXXX
>         service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: 'true'   defaultBackend:
>     resources:
>       requests:
>         cpu: 5m
>         memory: 5Mi   enabled: true   rbac:
>     create: true
>     scope: false   serviceAccount:
>     create: true   tcpExternalConfig: 'true'   ingressclass: gitlab01-nginx

